# Displaying FlatList using array of objects

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm new in react-native I have this data and I wanna get the privateUrl in my Flatlist.

```
console.log(information)
```

Return :

```
{
"images": [
    {
      "_id": "60a39eda33c50c377afd9cef",
      "name": "155055995_4635322536484663_1177699315069654339_n.jpg",
      "sizeInBytes": 677009,
      "publicUrl": null,
      "privateUrl": "tenant/607b7b33b168410028b2a095/informations/images/dad8915d-2292-4a9a-be2e-1b2fe711069f.jpg",
      "updatedAt": "2021-05-18T14:07:42.859Z",
      "createdAt": "2021-05-18T14:07:42.859Z",
      "id": "60a39eda33c50c377afd9cef",
      "downloadUrl": "http://172.16.224.151:8080/api/file/download?privateUrl=tenant/607b7b33b168410028b2a095/informations/images/dad8915d-2292-4a9a-be2e-1b2fe711069f.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "email": null,
  "site_web": "https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/solve-merge-conflicts/",
  "num_Tel": null,
  "type": "news",
  "publish": "true"
}
```

and this is my Flatlist :

```
     <FlatList    
        data={information}
        windowSize={60} 
        initialNumToRender={6} 
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <HotelItem
            block
            image={image}
            name={item.titleFR}
            location={item.createdAt}
            style={{ marginLeft: 15, marginBottom: 15 }}
            onPress={() => {
              /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
              navigation.navigate('HotelDetail', {
                infoId: item._id,
              });
            }}

          />
        )}
      />
```

and I wanna get the privateUrl in my flatlist and i tried this :

```
 image={item.images.privateUrl}
```

but not working .

Answer (score 0):

`images` is an array. If you want to refer to the first element of the array it should be `item.images[0].privateUrl`.

Is there always just one image? I am trying to think why `images` is an array and not just an object

Comment: Thanks, Ron B for the quick response, so simply because I can upload more than an image.
and in this case, I wanna show the first element in this array. 
I tried to write something like this, but I get the error "Cannot read property 'privateUrl' of undefined

Comment: HI Developers , i tried this and working for me :

 image={item.images[0]}
and in the compoenent :
<Image   source={{uri:`${image.privateUrl}`}} />